# Load large CSV data to PostgreSQL using Scala

Tags: postgresql, scala, csv

I had an assignment in which I had to load large amounts of data from CSV files into a PostgreSQL database using Scala. I was able to do it successfully, however, I received a vague feedback stating that my code produces unexpected complications.

Data in CSV files is in the following format. The starting and ending locations of columns are static and provided apriori. The total size of all CSV files to be loaded is around 11GB (100+million data rows).

```
#ID000012345 1988 10 18 99 2200    7          xyza-msu  607850 -1618400
31 -9999  -9999    40 -9999 -9999 -9999    23    20 
30 -9999  -9999   500 -9999 -9999 -9999    90    20 
30 -9999  -9999   750 -9999 -9999 -9999   113    20 
30 -9999  -9999  1000 -9999 -9999 -9999   113    20 
30 -9999  -9999  1500 -9999 -9999 -9999   203    10 
30 -9999  -9999  2000 -9999 -9999 -9999    90    20 
30 -9999  -9999  2500 -9999 -9999 -9999    90    30 
#ID000012346 1988 10 19 99 1000    6          xyza-msu  607850 -1618400
31 -9999  -9999    40 -9999 -9999 -9999     0    30
```

Lines starting with `#` denote header information for the rows below that line. Thus, all rows below the header row belong to one observation and the data needs to be imported such that both header data and observation data (rows belonging to a header) are in PostgreSQL.

I wrote the following code in Scala:

```scala
// read CSV file
val lines: List[String] = Source.fromFile(file).getLines.toList;
var count: Int = 0;
var h_rec: List[String] = null;
var data_rec: List[String] = null;

lines.foreach(l => {
    // grab header record
    if (l.contains("#")) {
        sqlStr = "insert into balloonData_small2(ID, DATE, HOUR, H_COL1, H_COL2,   
                  H_COL3, H_COL4, H_COL5, H_COL6, DATA_COL1, DATA_COL2, 
                  DATA_COL3, DATA_COL4, DATA_COL5, DATA_COL6, DATA_COL7,  
                  DATA_COL8, DATA_COL9, DATA_COL10, DATA_COL11, DATA_COL12,  
                  DATA_COL13)  values ";
        h_rec = null;
        count = 0;
        h_rec = List(l.slice(0,1), l.slice(1,12), l.slice(13, 17)+ 
                     l.slice(18,20)+l.slice(21,23), l.slice(24,26), 
                     l.slice(27,31), l.slice(32,36), l.slice(37,45),  
                     l.slice(46,54), l.slice(55,62), l.slice(63,71));
    } 

    // get all data records per above header
    if (!l.contains("#")) {
        data_rec = null;
        data_rec = List(l.slice(0,1), l.slice(1,2), l.slice(3,8), l.slice(9,15),                  
                        l.slice(15,16), l.slice(16,21), l.slice(21,22), 
                        l.slice(22,27), l.slice(27,28), l.slice(28,33),  
                        l.slice(34,39), l.slice(40,45), l.slice(46,51));

        // add all data per sounding to insert query and cast all columns to 
        // correct data type
        sqlStr += "('"+h_rec(1).strip+"',"+h_rec(2).strip.toInt+","+h_rec(3).strip.toInt+","+h_rec(4).strip.toInt+","+h_rec(5).strip.toInt+",'"+h_rec(6).strip+"','"+h_rec(7).strip+"',"+h_rec(8).strip.toInt+","+h_rec(9).strip.toInt+","+data_rec(0).strip.toInt+","+data_rec(1).strip.toInt+","+data_rec(2).strip.toInt+","+data_rec(3).strip.toInt+",'"+data_rec(4).strip+"',"+data_rec(5).strip.toInt+",'"+data_rec(6).strip+"',"+data_rec(7).strip.toInt+",'"+data_rec(8).strip+"',"+data_rec(9).strip.toInt+","+data_rec(10).strip.toInt+","+data_rec(11).strip.toInt+","+data_rec(12).strip.toInt+"), "

        count += 1;

        // check if last record for the sounding is reached in the file
        if (count == h_rec(5).strip.toInt) {
            // remove trailing comma and white space from SQL command
            sqlStr = sqlStr.strip.stripSuffix(",");

            // insert all values to DB table for given sounding record 
            stmnt.execute(sqlStr);
        }
    }
})
```

My idea behind the above code was to parse the CSV files only once to avoid costly reading from disk.

How can I improve my solution and in what way, please?

Comment: Note: with sed/grep pipeline you could achieve this at I/O speed.

Comment: I am aware of that. However, the requirements are such that I have to read the files in Scala and then upload to Postgres.

Comment: Firing an SQL-statement for only a handfull  of records is the costly part. With a round-trip time of  1ms it would take 10K seconds for 100M rows. (assuming 10 records per chunk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what kind of assignment this is, so I'll give some hints, and leave the rest with you.

Calling `.toList` results in loading the whole 11GB into the memory, you can live without it:

```
val lines: Iterator[String] = Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines()
```

Eliminate the unwanted lines by calling `.filter` or `.filterNot`:

```
lines.filterNot(_.startsWith("#"))
```

Split values by using `String.split` method which accepts a regex:

```
line.split(" +")
```

Use pattern matching to extract and merge some of the `List` items:

```
List("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5") match {
  case v1 :: v2 :: v3 :: rest => v1 :: (v2 + v3) :: rest
}
```

You can create and send bulk inserts to dramatically reduce the execution time (it may still be too long, though). You can group the lines for that:

```
val groups: Iterator[List[String]] = lines.grouped(10000)
```

At the end of the `.map`, `.filter` chain, you will have an object of type `Iterator[String]` where `String` is a SQL script in the below form. Now you can call `.foreach` and execute your scripts in the DB.

```
insert into MyTable values ('1a', '1b'), ('2a', '2b'), ...., ('10000a', '10000b')
```